# Expected error handling

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, exceptions

Let's say I have a social media website. On this website, users can upload several pieces of information about themselves, including their phone number. To implement this, I have a class called `PhoneNumber` that represents the users phone number. But phone numbers are optional. I have this `PhoneNumber` class which is supposed to guarantee access to a users phone number, but it can't. How do I handle this?

My current approach is to, whenever there's a problem, assign a value to an `error` variable inside `PhoneNumber` that represents the problem in question (this could be an exception, a string, or an error code, it's irrelevant for this question). I also added a method to `PhoneNumber` called `isPhoneNumberAvailable()` that should be called before any of the accessors are used. If one of the accessors is called and the user hasn't added their phone number, I throw an `IllegalStateException`. But this doesn't seem like a good solution. I'm not sure why, I'm too new at this to explain it, but it seems like this could cause me some problems down the road.

Note that this question is language agnostic, the existence of an `IllegalStateException` in Java is purely coincidental.

EDIT: The solution is improving the model. I have guaranteed access to something I can't guarantee access to, which is bad design. My other problem was with the use of an `error` variable in class scope but that's beyond the scope of this question. See my follow up question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/245198/132717).

Comment: Having 'Hobbies' class (plural) was a bad idea to start with in the first place. Instead have Hobby (singular) class, and any user of it should use a list of Hobby objects. This will make your model much better.

Comment: If you edit the question, then where is the problem? we can just use an empty list of Hobby to indicate there is no Hobby. Am I missing something (?!?!)

Comment: Yes... It was a badly made question. Give me a minute to edit it.

Comment: Done, does that make more sense?

Comment: Sorry :)
Still no sense for me. If it is optional then say you have a User class, in this user class, you have a list of PhoneNumber objects. Because PhoneNumber is optional, the list might be empty. Where is any problem? What I think you want here is not really about option, but about what if the info in PhoneNumber was not valid. But I have to ask you for sure.

Comment: It's not a list, it's a single, unique value that might not exist.

Comment: Ok, I think you should rethink the model. You are giving "guarantee access to a users phone number" and above you have "But phone numbers are optional". Kind of strange here.

Comment: Thanks randomA! Talking to you and jhr clarified my problems. I'll leave this question and it's answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just have the `PhoneNumber` property on the `User` object set to null. That way you can test `if PhoneNumber == null`, then the user can't call the phone number, so your UI doesn't even need to show the option (or show that there's no phone number).

Once phone number is provided, initialize an instance of the `PhoneNumber` class with the user's phone number and assign it the `PhoneNumber` property on the `User` object. The user's phone number can be validated the first time it is provided, and then it would be guaranteed to exist and be called. If the validation fails on the first attempt, it throws an exception during instantiation, and thus the `PhoneNumber` object is never created.

If at a later stage, you decided to have multiple phone numbers, either you can add more properties to the `User` (i.e. `User.HomePhone`, `User.MobilePhone`), or have a list of `PhoneNumbers` that is instantiated to empty list. As phone numbers are added, a new `PhoneNumber` object is instantiated and added to the list. Both these approaches will also guarantee that you never have a `PhoneNumber` unless it holds a valid number.

In fact, I have done something similar for a `PhoneNumber` class for multi-factor authentication and this approach worked fine for me.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for the catch. I meant to say "not instantiated (and set to null)", but even that is redundant. I just changed it to "set to null". I also edited other places to fix this confusion. (This is what happens when you're typing late at night and sleepy...)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is where to handle possible errors, right? Among others you have the ways you described:

1. The client asks if phone numbers are available. This has the benefit of a clean and exception-free API. But what happens if the client never asked before accessing the numbers?
2. Your getter (within your `PhobeNumber`) throws an exception of nothing is available. The advantage here is that clients don't need two remember two API calls.

Both are valid ways to handle this and which you choose depends highly on your application and what you think should happen if no phone numbers are available. I, personally, prefer exceptions as you can't forget them but that is even a matter of style.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in responding to it I clarified my own ideas and I may have discovered the answer and another question. Is storing `error` variables bad practice? Because it doesn't seem right. Nevermind. I'll make a new question (if one doesn't already exist)