# What kind of exception to ask for out of range arguments?

Tags: ruby, exception-handling

What type of exception should I throw?

I have a console class which describes rectangle of cells which a user can index by passing in a coordinate:

```
width, height = 80, 25
console = Console.new(width, height)

x, y = 2, 5
point_on_screen = Point.new(x, y)
console[point_on_screen] = 'a'
```

I am now wondering what types of exception to throw when an index occurs out of bounds . That is, outside of the (constant!) domains x:[0, width] and y:[0, height]. I could throw a `RangeError` or an `ArgumentError` <sup>*</sup>.

1. Does it matter which type of exception to throw as long as the error message is useful?
2. Should I use the same exception type for both the construction of the console and the indexing? Are the two really semantically different?

<sup>*</sup> returning a kind of out of bounds object is possibly a better option - something like a Null Object Pattern - but not what I am wondering about here.

#### ArgumentError

One option is to throw an `ArgumentError` because the argument is obviously wrong, dimensions can never be non-negative. This is what I throw in example 1, because we ought to know in advance that the dimensions should be non-negative.

Example 1:

```
console = Console new(-3, 4) # Argument error
```

#### RangeError

Another option is to throw a `RangeError` because the argument is out of the valid range. I use these for indexing. The argument is always out of range if x < 0, but if x ≥ 0 then it depends on the width of the console if the x is in the domain.

Example 2:

```
console = Console.new(20, 40)
pt = Point.new(-3, 4)
Console[pt] # RangeError
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Does it matter which type of exception to throw as long as the error message is useful?**

In cases like this, I often defer to the [official docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Exception.html) for definitions and usage examples.

The docs for `RangeError` are a bit terse:

> **RangeError**
>   Raised when a given numerical value is out of range.
>
> `[1, 2, 3].drop(1 << 100)`
>   raises the exception:
>   `RangeError: bignum too big to convert into long`

And although the docs for `ArgumentError` imply encouragement towards a more specific `Exception`, one of the examples (in bold below) certainly seems like a potential match for your use case:

> **ArgumentError**
>   Raised when the arguments are wrong and there isn't a more specific *Exception* class.
>
> Ex: passing the wrong number of arguments
>   `[1, 2, 3].first(4, 5)`
>   raises the exception:
>   `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`
>
> **Ex: passing an argument that is not acceptable:**
>   `[1, 2, 3].first(-4)`
>   **raises the exception:**
>   `ArgumentError: negative array size`

Generally speaking, `Argument`-type exceptions are a clear and expected way to convey to the caller that they've supplied some invalid parameters.

Regarding your mention of "*... as long as the message is helpful...*", I say yes, absolutely. **Always try to include a meaningful message when you raise an error.**

Regarding the null object alternative: Personally, I'd encourage you to explicitly raise the error rather than return a null object (or some other out-of-bounds indicator). Code built with this pattern is plagued by constant null checks, and inevitably a null object will escape your safety nets and wreak unexpected havoc on your program.

When I'm working with software that routinely returns nulls or special values as a "something went wrong" indicator, I need to spend additional mental cycles to make sure I'm checking all responses, and that I'm looking for the right error flags. (But, convention is certainly a factor, so if you're working with an existing code base which uses the null object pattern, it might be best to continue.)

Here's some good additional reading about exceptions vs. error variables: [Are error variables an anti-pattern or good design?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245198/are-error-variables-an-anti-pattern-or-good-design/245203#245203)

Comment: Thanks for the link and the extra pointer on the null object. I was also worried that sometimes it might be better to have an immediate exception thrown, rather than silently working with the null object, although I suppose I could have done some logging...

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a custom exception if you dont find the exceptions you have at your disposal fit correctly.

```
class MyUsefulException < Exception
end

raise MyUsefulException, 'Huzzah, my exception lives!!!'
```

Comment: Custom errors should derive from StandardError or something derived from that. Exception is a low level class that user code should not directly inherit.

Comment: @thomthom that was more just psuedo-code placeholder, where `Exception` could be any of the classes in the `Exception` Hierarchy tree. I am in agreement with you that you should inherit from `StandardError` in most cases.